# Ссылка на поле другой модели

Tags: django

Не могу решить такую задачку...
Имеется Django 2.2 Python 3.7 и два приложения news и users.
Необходимо в модели *Post* приложения *news* сделать ссылку на поле *username* в модели *User* приложения *users*...

**news.models.py**

```
from users.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    ****    
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        default='',
        verbose_name='Автор'
    )
```

**users.models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

***

username = models.CharField(
    'Имя пользователя',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
    db_index=True,
    blank=False,
    default='',
)

***

def __str__(self):
    return f'Пользователь - {self.username}, Почта - {self.email}'
```

---

В методе **__str__** я возвращаю имя пользователя и почту и это необходимо, но в HTML шаблонах, в переменную {{ post.author }} мне необходимо только имя пользователя... Вопрос такой, можно ли обойтись изменениями только в модели Post что бы не использовать циклы в шаблонах HTML, а пользоваться только {{ post.author }} и как это сделать?

P.S.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ****    
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User.username,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        default='',
        verbose_name='Автор'
    )
```

не работает:

> Traiceback: First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a mod el, a
>   model name, or the string 'self'

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно пишет. Первый параметр ForeignKey должен быть моделью, либо названием модели, либо указанием на саму себя, т.е. self. В вашем случае это должна быть модель `User`, уберите `.username`. Передавать field в foreignkey нельзя. В шаблонах можно просто обращаться к нему `{{ post.author.username }}` - никаких циклов для этого не надо

Comment: Больше спасибо! А Вы не могли бы дать ссылку на какую ни будь документацию по работе с шаблонами?

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar,  https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/templates/language.html